# RecyclerView returns null when activity is resumed

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView, which works fine when activity is started. When from that activity I go to another and come back, the recyclerView is empty. It shows nothing, however sometimes it returns values but the layout is disturbed i.e there would be either gaps between the items or the layout will have a large gap from the top of the activity.

The code for the class is:

```
public class product_page extends AppCompatActivity {

  FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  String s, product;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
  DatabaseReference databaseReference;
  DatabaseReference db;
  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProductItemsConstructor, productViewHolder> FirebaseAdapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_page);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        s = intent.getExtras().getString("pos");
        product = intent.getExtras().getString("product");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
   // RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    Query query = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Products").child(s).child(product).orderByKey();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductItemsConstructor>().setQuery(query,ProductItemsConstructor.class).build();

    FirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProductItemsConstructor, productViewHolder>(options) {


        @Override
        public productViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items,parent,false);
            return new productViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull productViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ProductItemsConstructor model) {
            holder.Heading(model.getHeading());
            holder.Price(model.getPrice());
            holder.Prates(model.getPprice());
            holder.Rating(model.getRating());
            holder.setImg(getApplicationContext(),model.getImageUrl());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseAdapter);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent in = new Intent(product_page.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}

public class productViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView head, rate, Prate, rating;
    ImageView img;


    public productViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void Heading(String heading) {
        head = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Pheading);
        head.setText(heading);
    }

    private void Price(String price) {
        rate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Pprice);
        rate.setText(price);
    }

    private void Prates(String prate){
        Prate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pRate);
        Prate.setText(prate);
    }

    private void Rating(String rting){
        rating = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rating);
        rating.setText(rting);
    }

    private void setImg(Context ctx, String img1) {
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PImage);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(img1).placeholder(R.drawable.notification).into(img);
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is the image when the activity is started first

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joopn.jpg)

This is the image when activity is resumed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ4qJ.jpg)

the log is shown below

> $ adb shell am start -n "com.strease.user.strease/com.strease.user.strease.SplashScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
>   Connected to process 22007 on device motorola-moto_g__4_-ZY223L3X8L
>   Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
>   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.strease.user.strease-2/lib/arm
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
>   D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 1wU7rrZpvLRCJeXeRITJkIXTu492 ).
>   D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
>   V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 1598141556
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
>   I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
>   W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
>   I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
>   V/FA: Collection enabled
>         App package, google app id: com.strease.user.strease, 1:841596997979:android:0ece7b89e3bda9c3
>   I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
>         To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>         To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>           adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.strease.user.strease
>   D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
>   V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>         Activity resumed, time: 33782085
>   I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100120}]
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
>   I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 7d18700, I8ee426a9a2
>             Build Date                       : 10/07/16
>             OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
>             Local Branch                     : mybranch22308589
>             Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.6_rb1.6
>             Remote Branch                    : NONE
>             Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>   D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>   V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4017
>   V/FA: Activity paused, time: 33786100
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=4017, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100120}]
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
>   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 33786801
>   I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashScreen, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-132049841330100120, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100119}]
>   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
>   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000cd/n/armeabi-v7a
>   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000cd/n/armeabi
>   W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
>   W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
>   D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 1wU7rrZpvLRCJeXeRITJkIXTu492 ).
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 1wU7rrZpvLRCJeXeRITJkIXTu492 ).
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>   D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
>   W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for FCM Token found on class com.strease.user.strease.userInfoConstructor
>                  No setter/field for Number found on class com.strease.user.strease.userInfoConstructor
>                  No setter/field for Email found on class com.strease.user.strease.userInfoConstructor
>   W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
>   I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=18KB, data=30KB
>   I/art: After code cache collection, code=13KB, data=27KB
>          Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   V/FA: Session started, time: 33792791
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100119}]
>   V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 23339
>   V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   V/FA: Activity paused, time: 33810138
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=23339, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100119}]
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 33810224
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-132049841330100119, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=product_page, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100118}]
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>   I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=42KB, data=62KB
>   I/art: After code cache collection, code=42KB, data=62KB
>          Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 10218
>   V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   V/FA: Activity paused, time: 33820442
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=10218, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=product_page, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100118}]
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
>                                  Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
>   I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>         Activity resumed, time: 33821178
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=product_page, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-132049841330100118, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Checkout_page, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100117}]
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 18503
>   V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   V/FA: Activity paused, time: 33839680
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=18503, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Checkout_page, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100117}]
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>         Connection attempt already in progress
>   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 33839706
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Checkout_page, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-132049841330100117, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=product_page, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-132049841330100118}]
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Any help or exlpanation would be appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
public class product_page extends AppCompatActivity {


FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String s, product;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
DatabaseReference db;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProductItemsConstructor, productViewHolder> FirebaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_page);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        s = intent.getExtras().getString("pos");
        product = intent.getExtras().getString("product");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
   // RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    Query query = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Products").child(s).child(product).orderByKey();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductItemsConstructor>().setQuery(query,ProductItemsConstructor.class).build();

    FirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProductItemsConstructor, productViewHolder>(options) {


        @Override
        public productViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items,parent,false);
            return new productViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull productViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ProductItemsConstructor model) {
            holder.Heading(model.getHeading());
            holder.Price(model.getPrice());
            holder.Prates(model.getPprice());
            holder.Rating(model.getRating());
            holder.setImg(getApplicationContext(),model.getImageUrl());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseAdapter);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    FirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent in = new Intent(product_page.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}

public class productViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView head, rate, Prate, rating;
    ImageView img;


    public productViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void Heading(String heading) {
        head = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Pheading);
        head.setText(heading);
    }

    private void Price(String price) {
        rate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Pprice);
        rate.setText(price);
    }

    private void Prates(String prate){
        Prate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pRate);
        Prate.setText(prate);
    }

    private void Rating(String rting){
        rating = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rating);
        rating.setText(rting);
    }

    private void setImg(Context ctx, String img1) {
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PImage);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(img1).placeholder(R.drawable.notification).into(img);
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Can you pls post the log.@JaspreetSingh

Comment: i will, however there is no error in the log as well. @Mayur Patel

Comment: I have added the log, please look forwrd to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make only these changes on your onResume() method ..

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

   //FirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   getData();
   }
}
private void getData() {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    // RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView = (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator());

    Query query = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Products").child(s).child(product).orderByKey();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductItemsConstructor>().setQuery(query, ProductItemsConstructor.class).build();

    FirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProductItemsConstructor, productViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public productViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = android.view.LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false);
            return new productViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@android.support.annotation.NonNull productViewHolder holder, int position, @android.support.annotation.NonNull ProductItemsConstructor model) {
            holder.Heading(model.getHeading());
            holder.Price(model.getPrice());
            holder.Prates(model.getPprice());
            holder.Rating(model.getRating());
            holder.setImg(getApplicationContext(), model.getImageUrl());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseAdapter);
    FirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still the same, however this time, when the activity was started first, the recyclerView was empty.